Stopping extension service worker execution asynchronously
I am currently developing a chrome extension. When the user starts the functionality, some async codes starts executing (which includes interaction with the active webpage via content scripts).
I want to handle the situation where the user navigates to a different webpage (e.g., by typing the url into the address bar) - and stop execution of the code in the service worker.
The only reasonable solution I have come up so far is using chrome.runtime.reload():
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Stop Extension Service Worker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {},
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}

background.js:
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => {
  chrome.runtime.reload();
});

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  // when user starts extension, some async website interactions are started
  console.log("started operation");
  setTimeout(() => {console.log("finished async operation")}, 4000);
});

Is this the recommended way to achieve that?
Another very idea that works, but is very cumbersome, is:

when user navigates away, toggle some storage.local boolean variable
check that variable inside the service worker as often as possible and return if it is set

